# "Invalid subject" when trying to assert on CSS properties with Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I created some end-2-end with cypress. Locally tests work fine, but when these tests run on CircleCI it shows errors from cypress

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

  > css

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

  > 250px

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.
```

And this is the code responsible for this error.

```
    cy.get('.vce-single-image')
      .should('have.css', 'width')
      .and('have.css', 'height')
```

The same error for this one.

```
    cy.window()
      .then((win) => {
        cy.get('.vce-row')
          .should('have.css', 'width')
          .and('have.css', 'height')
      })
```

I tried to add `first()` after `get()` but it didn't help. I tried it locally on different devices and there're no problems with that.

For CircleCi docker image I use own image, which is based on `circleci/php:7.3.2-apache`. Here is the link https://github.com/wpbakery/ci-wordpress/blob/master/circleci/Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, [`cy.should()`](https://on.cypress.io/should) yields the value that it was chained off of. However, [some assertions, including `have.css`, change the subject yielded by `cy.should()`](https://on.cypress.io/should#Yields). (here is the relevant [`chai-jquery` documentation](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#cssname-value))

So, this should work:

```js
cy.get('.vce-single-image').should('have.css', 'width', '250px')
cy.get('.vce-single-image').should('have.css', 'height', '250px')
```

Relevant reading: [How do I know which assertions change the subject and which keep it the same?](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#How-do-I-know-which-assertions-change-the-subject-and-which-keep-it-the-same)